# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, csv

I have been trying to combine files, and I keep getting a variety of errors each time I try to run it Error in

```
list.files(path = "~/Documents", full.names = FALSE) %>% lapply(read_csv) %>%  :  could not find function "%>%"
> write.csv(data, file = "Fecundity.csv", row_names = FALSE)
Error in utils::write.table(data, file = "Fecundity.csv", row_names = FALSE,  : 
unused argument (row_names = FALSE)

> write.csv(data, file = "Fecundity.csv", row.names = FALSE)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
> write.csv(data, file = "Fecundity.csv", row.names = TRUE)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

this is the code

```
library(data.table)
setwd(/cloud/project/Data sheets)
files <- list.files(pattern = ".cvs")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep= ".")
data <- rbindlist(temp)
write.csv(data, file = "Fecundity.csv", row.names = FALSE)`
```

Comment: You probably have nothing assigned to  `data`, and `data`  already exists as `"function"` object.

Comment: The "could not find function "%>%" probably stems from the fact that you need to (install and) load the dplyr package first using `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`. At the end of the %>% piping, you should assign the resulting object to an object "data" like this: `data <- list.files(<code>) %>% lapply(<code>)`. Before writing `data`, make sure that it is actually a data.frame and not a list (which is usually returned by `lapply()`). Check the class and structure using `str(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.

```
library(data.table)
library(fs)


files = dir_ls("csvFiles", regexp = "\\.csv$")
if(length(files)>0){
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    lines = fread(text = files[i], sep = "|", header=FALSE)
    fwrite(lines, "csvFiles/Fecundity.csv", append = TRUE)
  }
}
```

This is the fastest way I know. This code will read thousands of files in seconds!